# Android Studio weird Exception makes the updating UI from thread successful

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I create a new project in Android Studio 3.5.1, the Exception information shows in the Logcat window and Run window
`"Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper> ... (thousands lines omitted)"`. But the emulator works well with this exception, so I write code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv.setText("hello!");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I expect the exception information "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.". But it doesn't show up, instead, the text of the TextView has being changed!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120750246  this thread shows the weird exception information.